# Can't execute history command through Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line

I am able to get expected output using:

```
puts `ls` # listing of current directory
```

But I am unable to get the command history using the similar call:

```
puts `history` # Error - No such file or directory - history (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history` command is disabled in non-interactive sessions, but you should be able to access history directly form the file:

```
`cat ${HOME}/.bash_history`
```

(tested on Ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks! Will be using this solution.

Answer (score 1):

`history` is not a built-in command in the shell. In zsh, for instance, it’s an alias to this:

```
fc -l 1
```

You can use that command from Ruby to get the history. But I don’t think it’ll work how you expect, since the shell that Ruby starts up will *have* no history!

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is an "external" command that is usually located in `/bin/ls`. `history` on the other hand is *not* an external command but is built-in into your shell, usually bash or zsh.

Now in the shellouts, Ruby uses the `/bin/sh` shell by default which does not have history commands available.

Note that even though `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` are usually the same binary, Bash behaves differently when executed as `/bin/bash`. That's what you are seeing here.